# Any convex Reinhardt domain is logarithmically convex

Tags: complex-analysis, several-complex-variables

I have the following question in Shabat p.59:

Prove that any convex Reinhardt domain is logarithmically convex.

I think I have a good idea about how to show this, but need to be clear on the definitions first, which I'm a little unsure about. 
Specifically, the concept of a convex domain in $\mathbb{C}^n$. I'm assuming this is simply a domain in $\mathbb{C}^n$ such that for two points in $D \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ given by $z = (z_1,...,z_n), w = (w_1,...,w_n)$, we have the line  $   tz + (1-t)w \in D$, for $t \in [0,1]$.

So it remains to show that $ t \text{ ln}|z| + (1-t)\text{ ln}|w| \in \mathbb{R}^n$ for $t\in [0,1]$.

Also, the definition of a Reinhardt domain is the standard one: for $(z_1,...,z_n) \in D$, we have $(z_1e^{i\theta_1},...,z_ne^{i\theta_n}) \in D$.

Is this the correct formulation, or am I way off?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if $U$ is a convex Reinhardt domain then $U$ is a complete Reinhardt domain. As $U$ is convex then $U$ is a domain of holomorphy and by theorem [Theorem 7.4.5](https://books.google.com.pe/books?id=p3k-jW1USlAC&pg=PA124#v=onepage&q&f=false), $U$ is logarithmically convex.

Comment: This proof is not illuminating at all. K.Reeves is only up to page 59 of Shabat, and therefore, he is asking for a proof that does not use higher order machinery. Therefore, a direct proof would be more suitable here.